# Android set repeating alarm using Joda Time

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, jodatime, repeatingalarm

I am trying to set Android Alarm 2nd Monday and Wednesday of every month using JodaTime. I have been searching the internet for hours but I couldn't find what to put for the interval in `alarmMgr.setRepeating()` when I use JodaTime. Here is my code with the problem:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

public class SampleAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
 public static int firstOrSecond; //used for 1st, 2nd....
    //Joda time calculation for 1st, 2nd... sunday, monday... of month
    public static LocalDate nthWeekdayOfMonth(int dayOfWeek, int month, int year, int n) {
        LocalDate start = new LocalDate(year, month, firstOrSecond);
        LocalDate date = start.withDayOfWeek(dayOfWeek);
        return (date.isBefore(start)) ? date.plusWeeks(n) : date.plusWeeks(n - 1);
    }

// BEGIN_INCLUDE(set_alarm)
    public void setAlarm(Context context) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 700, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, MainActivity.hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, MainActivity.minute);

        //Using Joda Time
        DateTime jodaCal; 
        jodaCal = new DateTime(calendar);
        DateTime triggerMillis = new DateTime();
        triggerMillis = jodaCal.isBefore(triggerMillis) ? jodaCal.plusWeeks(firstOrSecond) : jodaCal.plusWeeks(firstOrSecond - 1);
        long jodaMillis = triggerMillis.getMillis();

        //Set repeating alarm
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                jodaMillis, /*What to put here for interval if I want to repeat alarm 2nd Wednesday of Every Month*/, alarmIntent);

        // Enable {@code SampleBootReceiver} to automatically restart the alarm when the
        // device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read this: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html also consider that RTC_WAKEUP alone might not be the best as the 2nd Monday of every month may not occur exactly the same number of minutes/hours/days/weeks as the prior one.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I read the link but looks like Android Calendar does not have the functionality to calculate every 2nd Weekday of the month that JodaTime provides. Also, what is the better option other than RTC_WAKEUP?